# How to enable CORS tomcat 8.5 filter to access static files?

Tags: java, tomcat, cors

i read lots of similar questions but none of given solution worked for me, so i am posting another one :/ I have to get, from my angular client, some pdf files on my Tomcat 8.5.37 server, but i am regularly blocked by Cors policy.

How can I add Cosr headers correctly?

I am working with Tomcat 8.5.37 (localhost actually),

First of all, I created a folder for that files under /webapps/my-files, and i put in it a simple "file.pdf", then i added in my server.xml, in  tag, the following:

`<Context docBase="/my-files" path="/web-docs"></Context>`

then I put this in my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My client app is an Angular 7 app, and I am using "ng2-pdf-viewer" module to show pdf files. According to module documentation, it makes a HTTP get call to specified URL to get the file and show it. According, i can see the get call in my Chrome console, session "Network". In "Response headers" session, i can see some headers like "Content-Type" and "Content-Lenght" with right values, but all other standard Cors headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods ecc...) are missing.

If I use a Chrome extensions to simulate Cors headers, I right get the pdf file and the component works as expected, but without this extension i get Cors blocking.

I put that Cors Filter in my web.xml file, in first position in "Built-in Filter Definition" session, but it didn't work. 
I added lots of `<init-param>`, according to Tomcat official documentation, but it didn't work. 
I tried to use a custom Cors Filter, with an `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` implementation and using `ContainerRequestContext` and `ContainerResponseContext` implememtation too, but both didn't work.

When i write "http://localhost:8080/web-docs/file.pdf", my browser shows it. When i try to get the file from my client, i am blocked by CORS.

How can I set a good Cors filter to access that files from my app? Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the request url of Client App that is trying to access resource from Tomcat server.

Comment: the origin is http://localhost:4200/pdf and the requested resource is http://localhost:8080/web-docs/file.pdf

Comment: if you mean the specific get call url i don't know because external library don't show me explicit url. i use <pdf-viewer [src]="localhost:8080/web-docs/file.pdf "> in my angular app and the component makes the call

Comment: You have to verify the class org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter is loaded. check whether you have Catalina.jar within lib directory of your tomcat server, If you do then can you try to access pdf from angular client after restarting tomcat instance, if not include the jar and try.

Comment: i checked, catalina.jar is in /lib. i opened the jar with WinRar and the path is right and che CorsFilter class is there.

Comment: the funniest thing is: i put a simple println in my custom filter, when client app calls the file, i can see the line on tomcat console but response header are still missing! can't believe...

Answer (score 1):

Add as follows,

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: this works on Tomcat 8.5! Can you tell how to use actual patterns? I want to allow only for referers:
[https://ual.domain.pl/] and 'https://qua.domain.pl/'
Can you show example for not 80 port and all sub locations for example:
'https://uad.domain.pl:8080/*' ?

Comment: ok I figured out. It goes to <param-value> like this:
<param-value>https://uat.domain.pl,https://qua.domain.pl:8080</param-value>
:)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I suppose you might want to experiment with the `httpHeaders` property:

```
[src]="{ url: 'http://...', httpHeaders: { 'h1': 'v1', 'h2': 'v2', 'hn': 'vn' }}"
```

See https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#src. It refers to Mozilla's pdf.js properties, which include `httpHeaders`. It is [thus documented](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L132):

```
 * @property {Object}     httpHeaders - Basic authentication headers.
```

which is not very informative. However, ng2-pdf-viewer does mention `httpHeaders` [in conjunction with CORS](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/06800082718f83418d20a83fa6c719745188c395/src/app/app.component.ts#L26).

There's also `withCredentials`, but that's about sending cookies in CORS requests, and I don't think that's what your problem is about.

Comment: Solved: i had three different tomcat instances, and CATALINA_HOME was wrong. Fixed that variable and all works even without filter specifications. Sorry for big mistake